# How to implement form validation using a for loop and an array for errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, validation

I want to check inputs for emptiness on button click. I am filtering an array if one of the inputs is empty. I'm trying to add an error to the array for errors, My task is that I need to add an error only for those inputs that are empty, but the problem is that the error is added even for those inputs that are not empty.

```
<template>
    <form>
      <div v-for="(learning, i) in general.learnings" :key="i">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="general.learnings[i]"
          maxlength="120"
        />
      </div>
      <p
        style="background: red"
        v-for="(i, index) in errorList"
        :key="'A' + index"
      >
        {{ i }}
      </p>
      <button @click="save">Save</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    save(e) {
      
      this.general.learnings.filter((e, index) => {
        if (!e[index]) {
          this.errorList.push("Error")

        } else if (e[index] !== "") {
          this.errorList = [""];
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      errorList: [],
      general: {
        learnings: ["", ""],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I think that the problem lies in `this.errorList.push("Error")` you can look at this [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sea-ehy0c) you can write something in the input press the button after pressing delete and press again you will see that everything works awfully, I will be very glad if help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sun-8z8xg

I changed the p to be in the div, and only display the error of that index

```
<div v-for="(learning, i) in general.learnings" :key="i">
      <input type="text" v-model="general.learnings[i]" maxlength="120" />

      <p style="background: red" :key="'A' + index">
        {{ errorList[i] }}
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot after your answer, I slightly changed the structure of the code and now I think everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I applied @flaxon code where the error will only show for my index then I slightly changed the validation check inside the `save` method

```
<div v-for="(learning, i) in general.learnings" :key="i">
      <input type="text" v-model="general.learnings[i]" maxlength="120" />

      <p style="background: red" :key="'A' + index">
        {{ errorList[i] }}
      </p>
    </div>

save(e) {
  this.errorList = [];
  this.general.learnings.filter((e, index) => {
    if (e === "") {
      this.errorList.push("Error");
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
},
```